# How to force <li> blocks to the bottom

Tags: css, html, html-lists

I'm trying to come up with a classroom seating arrangement using html/css while the data will be supplied thru mysql/php. If you're the teacher and you're in front of the class, your view of the classroom would be the students will take the front seats first where in your view, they're in the bottom while the rest of the empty seats are on your top view.

To visualize, it's something like this:

let X = a seat represented by a 70px x 70px list formatted to look like a block
 where there's 8 columns and 5 row

a. This is how html/css normally works

X X X X X X X X      third row

X X X X X X X X      second row

X X X X X            first row

BLACK BOARD

b. This is what I want it to look like

X X X X X          third row

X X X X X X X X    second row

X X X X X X X X    front seat

BLACK BOARD

Regardless of the data from php/mysql, I'm looking for a way so that HTML/CSS or even jQuery can force the first blocks to go to the bottom first. Thank you.

My Code:

```
<?php require("connectdb.php"); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>jQuery Dynamic Drag'n Drop</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.ui.ipad.altfix.js"></script>


<style>
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
}

#contentWrap {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: solid 2px #EEEEEE;
}

#contentTop {
    width: 600px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}

#sortable li { margin: 20px 20px 1px 20px; 
padding: 1px;
 float: left; 
 width: 70px; 
 height: 70px; 
 font-size: 12px;
 text-align: center; 
 background-color:#cfcfcf;
 position: absoute;
 bottom: 0;
 display: inline-block;
 float: right;
 }


#contentRight {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#336600;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

#save
{    
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color:#336600;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
}
.on { background-color:#000000; color:#782322; }

            #header{
                background-color: #EEEEEE;
                font-weight: bold;
                width: 804px;
                margin-left: auto ;
                margin-right: auto ;
                padding: 2;
            }
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
//$(document).ready(function(){ 



    $(function() {

    $(document).bind('touchmove', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);  

        $("#sortable").sortable({ opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move', update: function()     {
            var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") +     '&action=updateRecordsListings'; 
            $.post("updateDB.php", order, function(theResponse){
            });                                                              
        }                                 
        }).addTouch();
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();

        //$("li").click(function(){
            //$(this).addClass("on");
        //});   
    });

//});   
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        session_start();
        $teacherID = $_SESSION['teacherID'];
        $classID = $_SESSION['csID'];
        $qryClass = "SELECT * FROM class_schedule WHERE csID = '". $classID ."';";
        $class = mysql_query($qryClass);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($class))
        {
            $subjCode = $row['subjCode'];
            $section = $row['section'];
            $semester = $row['semester'];
            $sy = $row['SY'];
            $time = $row['time'];
        }
    ?>
    <div id = "header">
        <?php 
            //echo "What do you want to do, " .$fname . "?<br>";
            echo "Subject: " . $subjCode . " Block: " . $section . " -     Semester:" . $semester . " - SY:" . $sy . " - " . $time;
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="contentWrap">
            <ul id="sortable">
                <?php
                session_start();
                $query  = "SELECT e.*, CONCAT(s.lname,', ', s.fname) name     FROM enrollment e, student s
WHERE e.studentID = s.studentID AND e.csID = '". $classID ."' ORDER BY sort;";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                $c = 0;
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
                {
                    //if($c != 4)
                        echo "<li id='recordsArray_'"     . $row['id'] . ">" . $row['name'] . "</li>";
                }
                ?>
            </ul>       

    </div>
    <div id="save">
        Blackboard
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, I really don't get where you're going. This question is unclear and you should provide some code to clarify. Seriously, how are people supposed to propose a solution with such information?

Comment: Can you provide us the HTML and css in example this will help us to understand your query and provide solution.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to paste the code. It's there now :D

Comment: Added some jQuery code specific to your posted code

Answer (score 0):

Pre-process it in PHP.

```
$seats = array('X', 'X', 'X',...);
$ordered_seats = array(array_splice($seats, 0 - (count($seats) % 8))); // puts the last row into the new array
while (count($seats) > 0)
{
    $ordered_seats = array(array_splice($seats, -8)); // take 8 seats at a time
}
```

Very easy to rewrite this in jQuery, by using `.remove()` to take the last row out of the DOM, put them in an array for safekeeping, then `.appendTo()` to re-insert them once you've got them ordered.

---

jQuery (not tested):

```
var seats = $('#sortable .block');
var ordered_seats = seats.splice(0 - (seats.length % 8)).pad(8, '') || [];
while (seats.length > 0)
{
    $.merge(ordered_seats, seats.splice(-8));
}
// You now have the <li>s in the correct order
$('#sortable').html(''); // blank the container
for (var i in ordered_seats)
{
    $('#sortable').append(ordered_seats[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply so far. Btw, in your second code. What does the .block in the first line do?

Comment: jQuery selector to get all elements with a class of `block` inside an element with the id of `sortable`

Comment: Oh about that, I removed the .block class since it doesn't really do anything. The formatting of the li is under #sortable li in the CSS

Comment: Hmm two things
1. Is the pre-processing in PHP necessary for my code? Because I personally think that the problem lies in the graphic aspect but not the data processing. If yes, do I have to replace the X's in the array with the actual data, basing from my code, the $row['name']?

2. I'm using the sortable plugin of jquery so that I can drag the blocks. I was just wondering where I would be inserting the second code that you have provided.

Sorry for being too demanding, I'm a newbie at this stuff. :D

Comment: Change the first line to have `li` instead of `.block` then :) And you can either use the PHP or the jQuery. Probably easier to just use the jQ, and put it right at the end of your document, just before `</body>`, in `<script>` tags

Comment: Hmm nothing seems to have changed. The bottom row still has the fewer seats.